# Using ThreadPoolExecutor in web app

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I planning to use **ThreadPoolExecutor** in one of my web app but I have queries like 
what if my ThreadPoolExecutor shutdown/terminates when app don't get requests. Do I have to check the status and start new **ThreadPoolExecutor** object. When automatic termination/shutdown will happen actually?

When I ran below test scenario, it is not shutting down/terminating.
My Scenario is like:
My web app contineously gets requests read params, send ACK and do some further processing with params.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadPoolTester tt = new ThreadPoolTester();
    BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue = new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>();

    ThreadPoolExecutor ex = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, workQueue);
    while(true){
    tt.executor(ex);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }


}

public void executor(ThreadPoolExecutor ex){

    ArrayList<Future<String>>  tasks= new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
    if(ex.isShutdown()){
        System.out.println("threadpool is shutdown");
    }
    if(ex.isTerminated()){
        System.out.println("threadpool is terminated");
    }
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){           
    Future<String> task = ex.submit(new MyTask(i));
    tasks.add(task);
    System.out.println("Pool Size "+ex.getPoolSize());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        try{
        System.out.println("Retunr value: "+ tasks.get(i).get());           
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("final size "+ex.getPoolSize());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ThreadPoolExecutor itself will never shut down. However, it will shut down its threads if they are idle for longer than the keep alive time you specified. But it will create new threads on demand automatically.

So you don't have to do anything.

If you even want the threads to be kept alive forever, you can use a fixed size thread pool, but of course this is not scalable.